# When using 'gotoScene', the scene appears, but the previous scene remains too

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm currently trying to get an app in Corona to move to a new scene. After much trial and error, and looking at the examples from others, I have got my second scene loading onto the screen.

However, when the second scene is loaded, there is no transition, and the previous scene stays visible too, leaving both scene1 and scene2 visible.

My `main.lua` file:

```
local composer = require("composer")

display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

composer.gotoScene("scene1")
```

My `scene1.lua` file:

```
local composer = require("composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create(event)

  local sceneGroup = self.view

  local transitionOptions =
  {
    effect = "fade",
    time = 2000
  }

  local function gotoScene2(event)

    composer.gotoScene("scene2", transitionOptions)

  end

  local rect = display.newRect(display.contentCenterX, 
display.contentCenterY, 50, 50)

  rect:addEventListener("tap", gotoScene2)

end

scene:addEventListener("create", scene)

return scene
```

My `scene2.lua` file:

```
local composer = require("composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create(event)

  local circ = display.newCircle(display.contentCenterX, 100, 25)

end

scene:addEventListener("create", scene)

return scene
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
sceneGroup:insert( rect )
```

at end of `scene:create` function in `scene1.lua` file. It also apply to `circ` in  `scene2` scene.

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/system/composer/index.html)

> Remember that you must insert scene display objects into the scene's
>   self.view group. If you create display objects but do not insert them
>   into this group, they will reside in front of the Composer stage and
>   they will not be regarded as part of the scene. For display objects
>   which should be part of the scene and "managed" by Composer — for
>   example, cleaned up when the scene is removed — you must insert them
>   into the scene's self.view group